# How to manage Slow Query in MySQL compare item by item with 2 table Master Detail?

Tags: mysql, sql

please Help me..
I have a query like below:
Here is a table:

1. delivery_order
2. delivery_order_item
3. bst
4. bst_item

What I need is that I want to display goods that are in the delivery_order/item table that are not in the bst/item table according to the KODE_BARANG and the JUMLAH,

I have the Query below but it's still SLOW if the data is already a lot (the slow part is in the row when comparing KODE_BARANG),
I want to ask if any of my friends have experienced a similar case and how to solve it?
Thank you in advance, I hope someone here is willing to answer.

```
SELECT
    del.KODE_DO,
    deli.KODE_BARANG,
    deli.NAMA_BARANG,
    deli.JUMLAH,
    deli.SATUAN,
    @DITERIMA := COALESCE ((
        SELECT
            SUM( JUMLAH ) 
        FROM
            bst_item 
        WHERE
            KODE_PENERIMAAN = deli.KODE_DO
            AND KODE_BARANG = deli.KODE_BARANG  #this line that makes it slow 
            AND `STATUS` <> 0),0) AS DITERIMA,
    COALESCE ( deli.JUMLAH, 0 ) - @DITERIMA AS SISA
FROM
    delivery_order del
    INNER JOIN delivery_order_item deli ON del.KODE_DO = deli.KODE_DO
WHERE
    DATE(del.TANGGAL) >= :TGL1
    AND DATE(del.TANGGAL) <= :TGL2  
    AND COALESCE ( deli.JUMLAH, 0 ) - COALESCE ((
        SELECT
            SUM( JUMLAH ) 
        FROM
            bst_item 
        WHERE
            KODE_PENERIMAAN = deli.KODE_DO
            AND KODE_BARANG = deli.KODE_BARANG  #this line that makes it slow 
            AND `STATUS` <> 0),0) > 0
```

```
SELECT
    del.KODE_DO,
    deli.KODE_BARANG,
    deli.NAMA_BARANG,
    deli.JUMLAH,
    deli.SATUAN,
    @DITERIMA := COALESCE ((
        SELECT
            SUM( JUMLAH ) 
        FROM
            bst_item 
        WHERE
            KODE_PENERIMAAN = deli.KODE_DO
            AND KODE_BARANG = deli.KODE_BARANG  #this line that makes it slow 
            AND `STATUS` <> 0),0) AS DITERIMA,
    COALESCE ( deli.JUMLAH, 0 ) - @DITERIMA AS SISA
FROM
    delivery_order del
    INNER JOIN delivery_order_item deli ON del.KODE_DO = deli.KODE_DO
WHERE
    DATE(del.TANGGAL) >= :TGL1
    AND DATE(del.TANGGAL) <= :TGL2  
    AND COALESCE ( deli.JUMLAH, 0 ) - COALESCE ((
        SELECT
            SUM( JUMLAH ) 
        FROM
            bst_item 
        WHERE
            KODE_PENERIMAAN = deli.KODE_DO
            AND KODE_BARANG = deli.KODE_BARANG  #this line that makes it slow
            AND `STATUS` <> 0),0) > 0
```

Comment: I recently ran into such a same issue. I used this service to optimise query a bit. Give it a try https://www.eversql.com/sql-query-minifier/

Comment: Please recreate a basic structure with data on dbfiddle in order to help you: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: Pls share the structure of the underlying tables, including all indexes, and the output from the explain.

Comment: @Badru Sallam  Did you accidentally repeat your query in your Question?  They look the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INDEX(KODE_PENERIMAAN, KODE_BARANG, `STATUS`)
```

And don't hide TANGGAL in a function call.  (cf "sargable")